# Gap on top of body page

Tags: html

[Please check here.](http://static9.me/clients/witza/about)

There is a gap on top of the page, its so weird! I checked in Firebug and there is no errors appearing. I validated and theres an error saying:

> Line 1, Column 1: Non-space
> characters found without seeing a
> doctype first.

And

> Line 1, Column 1: Element head is
> missing a required instance of child
> element title.

I looked and looked and looked and I still can't figure it out! can someone please help me.

Answer (score 2):

If you saved the HTML in UTF-8, some editors put a byte order mark (U+FEFF) at the start of the file. This could be your problem. (You wouldn't see it because it is a zero-width space.) There is [more info on this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) at Wikipedia.

Answer (score 1):

This one caught me out, wordpress will insert:

```
<style type="text/css">
    html { margin-top: 28px !important; }
    * html body { margin-top: 28px !important; }
</style>
```

into your theme without you remembering that it does it. Threw me!